# Apache camel simple enrich example

Tags: java, apache-camel

The reason I'm asking this is the fact that the feature is actually newborn(available as of 2.16) and I couldn't find any documentation about it.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
from("file://Goods")
                    .aggregate(constant(true), new mergeFiles())
                    .completionFromBatchConsumer()
                    .split(body().tokenize("\r\n"), new mapStrings())
                    .enrich()
                    .simple("http://remoteserver.com/sample.xml")
                    .aggregate(constant(true), new calcxml())
```

The code basically means to enrich the mapped resource based on an xml introduction(i.e calculate tax for each good), and it's returning this error:

```
org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.RequestEntity with value Good1 450 due java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: spark/Request : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

And I have no idea what this has to do anything with spark(another apache project which is related to bigdata and etc.). Maybe I'm doing something wrong here and the usecase was to use this kind of enrichment solely for spark?

Also the previous sections of code runs fine as tested in debug mode with log4j

Comment: Which Java version are you compiling and running against?

Comment: JDK 1.7, I don't think its related to JDK or is it?

Comment: Are you able to use JDK 1.8? The "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" error is related to the JDK version you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" means that you running your code with JDK lower than 1.8 and some libraries are compiled for 1.8. You need to check all libraries you using and try to find one that doesn't support JDK 1.7. From your exception it looks like "spark/Request" is the reason

Here is list of JDK versions and their codes:

- Java SE 8 = 52 (0x34 hex),
- Java SE 7 = 51 (0x33 hex),
- Java SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex),
- Java SE 5.0 = 49 (0x31 hex),
- JDK 1.4 = 48 (0x30 hex),
- JDK 1.3 = 47 (0x2F hex),
- JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex),
- JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file

Comment: Worked after changing JDK to 1.8